# How to order below code : a class member function calling a non-member function with class argument?

Tags: c++

It might be better to illustrate the problem with below code:

Note: It should be sufficient to just look at the lines commented and starting with `#`.

**Question**:
How to order lines #1, #2, #3, and #4? The tricky part is that #2 depends on #3 , but #3 depends on #1.
(Additional note: I was required to keep the constructor within the class body. )

```
/* --------------------Header-------------------- */

struct Sales_data {                              /* #1: class definition */

  /* #2: member function (calling a non-member function) */
  Sales_data(std::istream &is){read(is, *this); 
};

std::string bookNo;
unsigned units_sold = {0};
double revenue {0.0 };
};

/* #3: declaration of the non-member function */
std::istream &read(std::istream &is, Sales_data &item) ; 


/* --------------------Source-------------------- */
/* #4: definition of the non-member function */
istream &read(istream &is, Sales_data &item) {           
  /* .... */
}

int main(){
  /* .... */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can forward-declare structs and classes. So:

```
struct Sales_data;
std::istream& read(std::istream& is, Sales_data& item);
```

then everything else.

Comment: +1. Or you could just move the Sales_data constructor body to the .cc file...

Comment: @Nemo OP said that isn't an option: "(Additional note: I was required to keep the constructor within the class body.)"

Comment: @Nemo Thanks for the tip. But I was asked to keep it inside the class body.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Thankx for the tips. If I move it into class body, does it becomes a member function? - I just learn class today.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Ok I just realized it is not moved inside body. Just a declaration.